# Running two classes at the same time in android studio

Tags: java, android, multithreading

The way that I have my current application set up is that when you press the button then the app displays a counter on the bottom that goes up to ten then stops and then it displays a counter on the top that goes from 10 to 0. However, what I need to do is make these counters happen at the same time. I tried using threads but I think that I must not have been doing it right. Any help would be appreciated.

edit: I want to run mytask and mytask1 at the same time, they currently run after each other

edit2: I was asked for the code for publish progress

```
protected final void publishProgress(Progress... values) {
        if (!isCancelled()) {
            getHandler().obtainMessage(MESSAGE_POST_PROGRESS,
                    new AsyncTaskResult<Progress>(this, values)).sendToTarget();
        }
    }
```

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn;
TextView txt;
Integer count =1;
Integer count1 =10;
TextView txt1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   //p
   //p
   btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
   btn.setText("Start");
   txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
   txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
   View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View view){
           count =1;
           //p
           //p
           switch (view.getId()){
               case R.id.button:
                   new MyTask().execute(10);
                   new MyTask1().execute(0);
                   break;
           }
       }
   };
   btn.setOnClickListener(listener);

}


class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        for (; count <= params[0]; count++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                publishProgress(count);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "Task Completed.";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        txt.setText(result);
        btn.setText("Restart");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        txt.setText("Task Starting...");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        txt.setText("BackGround Task Running..."+ values[0]);
    }
}

class MyTask1 extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        for (; count1 >= params[0]; count1--) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                publishProgress(count1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "Task Completed.";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        txt1.setText(result);
        btn.setText("Restart");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        txt1.setText("Task Starting...");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        txt1.setText("Countdown "+ values[0]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: please add your code for the `publishProgress` function

Comment: @OmriAttiya I found it edited

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTasks are executed on a single thread according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask), so that might be the issue.